# Ansible - generate docs from role argument spec

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

Is there any way to generate a markdown documentation from ansible role argument spec?

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-argument-validation

I could not find anything in `ansible-doc`, the format itself suggests that there is a way

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for such a thing previously as well, and decided to write a small tool for it: https://gitlab.com/kankare/ansible-docs

I'm not actively using it for anything, so do let me know if it turns out being useful or not.